# Meaning of "sniped in"

Tags: meaning, sentence

What is the meaning of *sniped in*? Can I use it in the following sentence to replace *bought*?

> John has **bought/sniped in** a  new BMW.

Comment: This is general reference; see eg [Auction sniping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auction_sniping),  in wikipedia, which says:  "Auction sniping is the practice, in a timed online auction (such as on eBay), of placing a winning bid at the last possible moment (often seconds before the end of the auction), giving the other bidders no time to outbid the sniper."

Comment: bought is not equivalent to "sniped in". Sniped, as a slang, means to steal or take away something which belongs to someone else. I cannot find any reference where "sniped in" has been used (even as a slang).

Answer (score 3):

In relation to buying things, *sniping* is only relevant to online auctions sites such as eBay.

*Sniping* in this context is the action of placing a single bid at the last possible moment, to sneak ahead of other bidders. It is a metaphor for the action of snipers - long distance precision gunmen.

I have not heard this word used in the phrase "sniped in".

If Bob had won the BMW in an eBay auction by sniping, you might say:

> Bob sniped a brand new BMW.

... but be aware that it would only be understood by people who are very familiar with online auctions.

Answer (score 1):

"Snipe" (to attack, to criticize, to hunt the birds called 'snipe') and "in" do not collocate. (they don't make a natural pair, like "worry about something", as opposed to "worry from/to/behind/in something". Snipe has nothing to do with "buy".

"John has sniped in a new BMW" means that sometime in his life, John sat in a new BMW and either attacked or criticized someone or shot birds.

Comment: "Sniping" _does_ have a meaning to do with buying. But only via online auction sites.

Comment: Of course. I didn't mention it because it's already been said.